# "Transferring" ArcGIS Online content from one organization to another

Tags: arcgis-online

My organization is currently brainstorming with another organization on how continue providing access to about a half of dozen web applications and data through ArcGIS Online.

Currently, the organization we are in talks with wants to be able to hand off the content/web applications on ArcGIS Online to us to host on our ArcGIS online organizational account.

I haven't found anything that steers us in the right direction on GIS SE and on ArcGIS Online FAQ [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/faq.htm#anchor4) appears that this feature isn't entirely possible.

How would we go about doing this? If at all possible?

Comment: ESRI Github moving organizations https://github.com/Esri/ago-admin-wiki/wiki/Migrating-items-between-accounts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ArcGIS Online Assistant](https://ago-assistant.esri.com/) (free) and [Admin Tools for ArcGIS Online (Pro)](http://www.geo-jobe.com/admin-tools/) (paid) offer solutions for moving items to a different organization.

ArcGIS Online Assistant is more limited than Admin Tools for ArcGIS Online (Pro). Most notably, the paid Admin Tools for ArcGIS Online (Pro) clone tool will update references in web apps and web maps to the new versions of the feature services copied to the new org.

In some cases, especially with a relatively small number of items to move you can use the free ArcGIS Online Assistant to move webmaps and feature services, then use the "Update Web Maps Services URLs" tool in the free version of Admin Tools for ArcGIS Online to update the web maps to use the new feature service URLs.

Another limitation of the free ArcGIS Online Assistant is that it doesn't move files such as image files.

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: Can you please provide some more information on how to "update the web maps services URL" tool to update the web map. I am able to copy the map but am stuck on how exactly to update the URL

Answer (score 4):

We have found that the cloning logic in the Admin Tools for ArcGIS Online product will also transfer image files (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .tif, .tiff) as well as tiled services automatically (as long as the service definition is in the source org.) It will also transfer hosted feature services and provide the option to retain data and attachments before the transfer happens. Transferring (cloning) content with this tool is basically a point click operation if you need content transferred, it will handle the rest. However, it does cost $500/yr or $99/mo but its saving us like 3 days of work, along with everything else it does like View an Item's Dependencies, Email Users, Update, Find & Replace Content URLs, etc.

Anyway, here is a [video I found](https://youtu.be/3w6AsSx1nnQ?list=PLwtXY4lTNM_vS35NmbXAQXF9fbB2o9lOG) on how the cloning tool works

Comment: If you are a contractor cloning between 2 ArcGIS Online organizations, it is actually twice that price. From GEO Jobe's website: ** Please Note: For operations that involve actions performed on other ArcGIS Online organization accounts, such as cloning and csv import to another account, both Source and Destination organizations must have a Admin Tools Pro License."